# How to draw an Arc using core draw

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I want to draw an arc like in the following figure using core draw.

[image]

Not exactly same but I have background images set. I need to draw arc based on the file download. Now the percentage of download number I have. How can I do it using core draw?

Comment: <insert joke about using arc to draw an arc>

Comment: take a look to this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths

Answer (score 1):

The image above are just two circles - one is cutting a hole in another. This is not near to what you want to accomplish.

You need to use `CGContextAddArc`.

Do something like this:

- open a path
- move to a point
- start drawing the Arc with `CGContextAddArc`
- move (and draw a line) inwards to the arc center the desired width of the slice
- draw an backward arc
- close the path

Answer (score 0):

Use Mid point Algorithm, If you want to draw circles , to make concentric circle provide difference in radius of your circles

Answer (score 0):

I have what you want:

```
// CircularProgress.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CircularProgress : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat percent;

@end

// CircularProgress.m

#import "CircularProgress.h"

@implementation CircularProgress

- (void)setPercent:(CGFloat)percent
{
    _percent = percent;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width / 2.0, bounds.size.height / 2.0);

    CGFloat lineWidth = 8.0;
    CGFloat innerRadius = (bounds.size.width / 2.0) - lineWidth;
    CGFloat outerRadius = innerRadius + lineWidth;
    CGFloat startAngle = -((float)M_PI / 2.0);
    CGFloat endAngle = ((self.percent / 100.0) * 2 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;

    UIBezierPath *processBackgroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    processBackgroundPath.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    CGFloat radius = (self.bounds.size.width - lineWidth) / 2.0;
    CGFloat fullAngle = (2.0 * (float)M_PI) + startAngle;
    [processBackgroundPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:fullAngle clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [processBackgroundPath stroke];

    CGMutablePathRef progressPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(progressPath, NULL, center.x, center.y - innerRadius);
    CGPathAddArc(progressPath, NULL, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, YES);
    CGPathAddArc(progressPath, NULL, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, NO);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(progressPath);

    UIColor *aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.941 green:0.776 blue:0.216 alpha:1.0];
    [aColor setFill];
    CGContextAddPath(context, progressPath);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGPathRelease(progressPath);
}

@end
```

You just need to create an object of `CircularProgress` class of the desired size (it should be square) and add it as subview to your main view. Then simply change the `percent` value and enjoy result. The color and width are hardcoded for now because it's not the finished control but you should catch the idea.